# Erro ao executar o mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql

Essa é minha linha 17 de programação:

```
$result = mysql_query($localhost, "SELECT *FROM **nome do meu banco**") 
or die (mysql_error());
```

Este é o erro que não consigo tirar:

> Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string
>   given in /home/u803520287/public_html/android/**nome do meu
>   banco**.php on line 17

Como corrigir?

Answer (score 3):

Basicamente é erro de digitação.

O manual do PHP é claro na ordem dos parâmetros:

```
mysql_query (string $query[, resource $link_identifier] )
```

Mais detalhes:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-query.php

Fica a sugestão de trocar as funções `mysql` por `mysqli`, que não estão obsoletas (e no caso, o link vem primeiro nestas).

Veja mais aqui: [Extensão MySQL Melhorada](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, comecei a 2 dias fazer programação e ainda tenho dificuldade em entender a ordem dos dados. fiz a atualização e deu 2 erros que seguem. 

 Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/u803520287/public_html/android/FindMe.php on line 17

Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /home/u803520287/public_html/android/FindMe.php on line 17

como deve ficar a linha que postei?

Comment: Estes dois erros você consegue localizar pesquisando no site: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=expects+parameter+1+to+be+mysqli , e o segundo é a falta do link da conexão nos parênteses `mysqli_error( $sua_conexao);`. Dê uma pesquisadinha em mysqli que tem vários exemplos no site e no manual http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php